# Tensorflow preprocessing split string to chars

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I want to write use  `TextVectorization` preprocessing layer but split strings into chars.

```
data = tf.constant(
    [
        "The Brain is wider than the Sky",
        "For put them side by side",
        "The one the other will contain",
        "With ease and You beside",
    ]
)
# Instantiate TextVectorization with "int" output_mode
text_vectorizer = preprocessing.TextVectorization(output_mode="int")
# Index the vocabulary via `adapt()`
text_vectorizer.adapt(data)
```

`TextVectorization` class have `split` param which can be a function.
On pure python I want to write something like this :

```
text_vectorizer = preprocessing.TextVectorization(output_mode="int",split=lambda x:list(x)))
```

but how should I write it in the TensorFlow world ?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `tf.strings.regex_replace` and convert each sequence into a single string first, then apply `tf.strings.regex_replace` again to split the string into characters. Next, use `tf.strings.strip` to remove the leading and trailing spaces from each string. Finally, split and return your strings:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def split_chars(input_data):
  s = tf.strings.regex_replace(input_data, ' ', '')
  tf.print('Single string --> ', s)
  s = tf.strings.regex_replace(s, '', ' ')
  tf.print('Characters --> ', s)
  s = tf.strings.strip(s)
  tf.print('Stripped --> ', s)
  s = tf.strings.split(s, sep = ' ')
  tf.print('Split --> ', s)
  return s

data = tf.constant(
    [
        "The Brain is wider than the Sky",
        "For put them side by side",
        "The one the other will contain",
        "With ease and You beside",
    ]
)
input_text_processor = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(split = split_chars)

input_text_processor.adapt(data)
tf.print(f"Vocabulary --> {input_text_processor.get_vocabulary()}")
```

```
Single string -->  ["thebrainiswiderthanthesky" "forputthemsidebyside" "theonetheotherwillcontain" "witheaseandyoubeside"]
Characters -->  [" t h e b r a i n i s w i d e r t h a n t h e s k y " " f o r p u t t h e m s i d e b y s i d e " " t h e o n e t h e o t h e r w i l l c o n t a i n " " w i t h e a s e a n d y o u b e s i d e "]
Stripped -->  ["t h e b r a i n i s w i d e r t h a n t h e s k y" "f o r p u t t h e m s i d e b y s i d e" "t h e o n e t h e o t h e r w i l l c o n t a i n" "w i t h e a s e a n d y o u b e s i d e"]
Split -->  [['t', 'h', 'e', ..., 's', 'k', 'y'], ['f', 'o', 'r', ..., 'i', 'd', 'e'], ['t', 'h', 'e', ..., 'a', 'i', 'n'], ['w', 'i', 't', ..., 'i', 'd', 'e']]
Vocabulary --> ['', '[UNK]', 'e', 't', 'i', 'h', 's', 'n', 'o', 'd', 'a', 'r', 'y', 'w', 'b', 'u', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'k', 'f', 'c']
```

Comment: This is workarond on the problem but not the solution.And it slightly differs from basic `split_chars`  : for example you loose the information about "<SPACE><SPACE>" and so on . I have found solution : there is a `tf.strings.unicode_split` function that just splits string into chars .

Comment: But my question is still exists - there are alot of some small transformer operations that can be done in tf. directly

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `split="character"` as outlined [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization)

This will vectorize each individual character in the output, preserving whitespace characters like newlines or spaces as vocabulary items themselves.

```py
text_vectorizer = preprocessing.TextVectorization(output_mode="int",split="character")
```